# Add new Address field setting in Scratch Org definition file

Tags: scratch-org, address, scratch-org-definition-file, user-interface

I need to automatically check the new User Interface setting : **Use custom address fields (Beta)** upon creation of a Scratch Org.

[image]

I am not sure what setting to add in the def.json file.
The following is not working:

```
"userInterfaceSettings": {
     "customAddressFieldEnabledOffOn" : true
}
```

[image]

Anyone know the correct setting to add to get Address field type enabled by default in the Scratch Org?

Comment: I figured it should look like `"customAddressFieldSettings": {"enableCustomAddressField": true }`, but that also didn't work. I'm not sure there is a way to do this yet. Sometimes beta features come with some limitations.

Answer (score 3):

Picking up sfdcfox' comment: Now that custom address fields are GA, it works in the scratch org definition file. Just add the settings like this:

```
"settings": {
    ...
    "customAddressFieldSettings": {
      "enableCustomAddressField": true
    }
  }
```

I will also test package creation later today and will update this post, if there are still limitations.

Comment: This worked for my scratch org creation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you retrieve CustomAddressField, in the Settings section of the metadata API, you will be able to enable in scratch org when you do the Push.

--CustomAddressField.Settings-meta.xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomAddressFieldSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableCustomAddressField>true</enableCustomAddressField>
</CustomAddressFieldSettings>
```

--package.xml--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>CustomAddressField</members>
        <name>Settings</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

Thank you